# Why does SIGINT not terminate a stopped process?

Tags: ubuntu, kill, signals, posix, interrupt

According to [the POSIX standard](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) regarding signals (see "Standard signals" section), both `SIGKILL` and `SIGINT` have as default action **Term**. However, this seems not to be the case when the receiving process has been stopped via `SIGSTOP` (or `SIGTSTP`).

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I create a program with an infinite loop:

```
int main(){
   while(1);
}
```

compile and run it

```
$ ./program
```

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to stop it. This causes a `SIGTSTP` signal to be delivered to this process. Now, if I send a `SIGINT` signal to the process via `kill -SIGINT pid`, and look at the process table: `ps -aux`, I see that it has not been terminated. However, if I send a `kill -SIGKILL pid` it does get terminated.

Why does `SIGINT` not behave in the same way as `SIGKILL`, if they both have the same default action (i.e. **Term**)?

Comment: `INT` needs to be received by the process (which can't happen while it is stopped). `KILL` is never actually received by the process anyway. This is not an answer as it does not show any example or references.

Comment: Try sending a `SIGTERM` since a nice shell will also send a `SIGCONT` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGKILL` will terminate a process by default and cannot be blocked, whereas `SIGINT` will terminate a process by default but can be blocked. Since you moved the process to the background with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> (`SIGTSTP`), the `SIGINT` signal will be blocked and will only be delivered to the process after it resumes its execution (`SIGCONT`).

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense, because when I execute `kill -SIGCONT pid`, SIGINT gets unblocked and the pending SIGINT signal is delivered, causing the process to terminate.